# Set Location in Google Maps API using JSON and save last known Location

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

I made JSON includes latitude and Longitude on My car. It's refreshing every 1 second. I retrieve this data using Retrofit and it's working. Earlier I display this data on textview's.

For now I have two issues. How can I place this two variables into google Map to create marker (or blue dot) and how can I save last known position (to retrieve it anytime when I haven't got connection with server.
In application I don't wanna use build-in GPS receiver, so location manager may be useless

main activity:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

LocationManager locationManager;
public static final String BASE_URL = "ip_of_server";
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

public Double lat;
public Double lon;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }

    getDataRunnable.run();

}


public void getData() {

    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

    }

    JsonPlaceHolderApi jsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);
    Call<OutputModel> call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.getCords();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<OutputModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<OutputModel> call, retrofit2.Response<OutputModel> response) {

            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                // onFailTV.setText("Code: " + response.code());
                return;
            }


            lat = response.body().getLatitude();
            lon = response.body().getLongitude();


            LatLng carPosition = new LatLng(lat, lon);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(carPosition).title("Integra Location"));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(carPosition, 15.5f));


        }


        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<OutputModel> call, Throwable t) {
            // onFailTV.setText(t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}

public Runnable getDataRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        getData();
        mHandler.postDelayed(this,1000);
    }
};

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;

}

}
```

my model class:

```
public class OutputModel {

@SerializedName("latitude")
private Double latitude;

@SerializedName("longitude")
private Double longitude;

@SerializedName("velocity")
private Double velocity;


public OutputModel(Double latitude, Double longitude, Double velocity) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.velocity = velocity;
}

public Double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public Double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public Double getVelocity() {
    return velocity;
}

public void setVelocity(Double velocity) {
    this.velocity = velocity;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GoogleMap a blue dot represents the location of the device, and you get it like this:

```
GoogleMap googleMap;
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

To create a Marker with Latitude and Longitude of you car you can do this:

```
   LatLng myCarLocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
   Marker myCarMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myCarLocation).title("My Car Marker"));
   googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myCarLocation));
```

And to save last know location i would suggest using Shared Preferences to save location every time you get the last location, and then use it whenever you need it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Shared preferences is good tip, but Your advice about marker I have in my code above and it doesn't work.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I think it (Marker) just need a title. I added an extra line below so google map moves to that location and you can verify. Hope that helps!

Comment: Okay, issue was in onCreate method. Works fine. thanks